# Почему я могу сделать дружественным класс, до которого определение ещё не дошло?

Tags: c++, классы

```
class Anything {
private:
    int m_count;
    friend class Temp;
public:
    Anything(int value = 0) : m_count(value) {};
};

class Temp {
private:
    int m_count;
public:
    Temp(int value = 0) : m_count(value) {};
};
```

Почему я могу сделать дружественным класс, до которого определение ещё не дошло. Как компилятор знает что существует класс `Temp`на этапе определение класса `Anything`?

А если сделать так, то это уже работать не будет, тк нужно объявить класс `Temp` в начале

```
class Anything {
private:
    int m_count;
    friend void out(const Anything& any, const Temp& temp);
public:
    Anything(int value = 0) : m_count(value) {};
};

class Temp {
private:
    int m_count;
    friend void out(const Anything& any, const Temp& temp);
public:
    Temp(int value = 0) : m_count(value) {};
};
```

Comment: Потому что это предварительное объявление ([forward declaration](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Comment: @Harry `class Temp;`, но оно без этой строки работает в случае с дружественным классом,  с функцией работает только с строкой выше

Comment: friend class Temp; объявляется  тип Temp  его другом. (вы сообщаете , что  директор ваш друг. Я это понимаю, хотя и не знаю что за директор(вы не  определили). Так что все нормально, пока  не начнется "рассказ" о нем).  А вот функция, принимающая аргумент, это уже и есть "рассказ" что это действие  с конкретными аргументами. Ну и естественно, что компилятор не зная об аргументах, просит вас  определить что это такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, в первом случае вы говорите

```
friend class Temp;
```

т.е. объясняете, что 1. `Temp` — это класс, и 2. что он друг. Пока что этого достаточно, компилятору не нужно знать внутренности этого класса, его размер и т.п.

Если же вы пишете

```
friend void out(const Anything& any, const Temp& temp);
```

то здесь говорится только, что вот такая функция с такими аргументами будет другом. Но что такое `Temp`? Может, это класс? Или, может, это просто алиас `int`а? а вдруг это еще какой тип? Ведь ничего не известно, что такое `Temp`! Вот поэтому в первом случае это работате как forward declaration, а во втором нет, потому что никакого forward declaration здесь нет.